# Can I use setlocale() and isalpha() to determine if character belongs to alphabet of current locale?

Tags: linux, unix, posix, locale, setlocale

Is it possible to do setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "ru_RU.utf8") and for each symbol of string "рус eng" do isaplha() check and to get as result following:

```
р alpha
у alpha
с alpha
  not alpha
e not alpha
n not alpha
g not alpha
```

now when I am setting locale ru_RU.utf8 all symbols except space symbol are alpha

Answer (score 3):

The `isalpha` function asks [the question](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/isalpha.html):

> The isalpha() function shall test whether c is a character of class alpha in the program's current locale.

and goes on to note:

> The c argument is an int, the value of which the application shall ensure is representable as an unsigned char or equal to the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.

Which means that it only works for ascii characters.

The test is pretty much is the character in the ranges `[A-Z]` or `[a-z]`, nothing more.

Noe if you want to test characters outside of this range, then you need to use one of the wide character variants such as [iswalpha](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/iswalpha.html).

What it looks like you're asking is if you can perform a test that will reject characters that are not explicit cyrillic letters? That's not going to work with the `iswalpha()` test because it assumes *all* alpha characters from pretty much all character sets are alpha characters - if you read the locale definition of ru_RU (glibc source [`localedata/locales/ru_RU`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/localedata/locales/ru_RU)), which uses the [`i18n`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/localedata/locales/i18n) file as it's data source for character types determines what is considered an alpha.

If the input data is truly only [from the russian alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_alphabet), then you can check if the character is non-ascii and if that is the case then accept it as a valid character; unfortunately there is a good chance that some characters that are typed e.g. `е` (i.e. CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER IE Unicode: U+0435, UTF-8: D0 B5) will be entered using the latin character `e` (i.e. LATIN SMALL LETTER E Unicode: U+0065, UTF-8: 65) and so would be missed by this test.

if you want to test for those cyrillic characters explicitly, then you need to test for the character ranges:

```
% CYRILLIC/ 
   <U0400>..<U042F>;<U0460>..(2)..<U047E>;/ 
   <U0480>;<U048A>..(2)..<U04BE>;<U04C0>;<U04C1>..(2)..<U04CD>;/ 
   <U04D0>..(2)..<U04FE>;/ 
% CYRILLIC SUPPLEMENT/ 
   <U0500>..(2)..<U0522>;/ 
% CYRILLIC SUPPLEMENT 2/ 
   <UA640>..(2)..<UA65E>;<UA662>..(2)..<UA66C>;<UA680>..(2)..<UA696>;/ 
% CYRILLIC/ 
   <U0430>..<U045F>;<U0461>..(2)..<U047F>;/ 
   <U0481>;<U048B>..(2)..<U04BF>;<U04C2>..(2)..<U04CE>;/ 
   <U04CF>;/ 
   <U04D1>..(2)..<U0523>;/ 
% CYRILLIC SUPPLEMENT 2/ 
   <UA641>..(2)..<UA65F>;<UA663>..(2)..<UA66D>;<UA681>..(2)..<UA697>;/
```

Comment: mmm, yes you are right. I've forgot to say about iswalpha() for wchar_t. I use them.

Comment: You should use `isspace`/`iswspace` in that case as an additional test

Comment: is iswspace with input 'e' symbol will return true? I need to filter other than alphabetical symbols of current locale

Comment: No, iswspace only deals with whitespace characters. you should combine conditions with the logical or (`||`) operator e.g. `iswspace(c) || iswalpha(c)` would be is it either a space or an alpha character

Comment: But I need following iswalpha(L'e') => false iswalpha(L'ю') => true. From your last comments I can't undertand how it relates to issue

Comment: That's not a test for alpha characters. That looks more to be a test of cyrillic specific characters. I'll update the answer